# data.success undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax

Working on a submission form with ajax, json and PHP.  The data is handled properly with the DB, but this script, with alert(data.success), says data.success is undefined.  If I alert(data), it shows what i need is there `{"success":"http:\/\/myaddress.com"}`

```
function confirmSubmit() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php?route=payment/authorize/send',
    data: $('#authorize :input'),   
    beforeSend: function() {
        var img = '<?php echo $text_wait; ?>';
        $('#authorize_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        $('#authorize').before('<div class="wait"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading_1.gif" alt="" /> ' + img + '</div>');
        alert('Start');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.error) {
            alert('errors...');
            alert(data.error);

            $('#authorize_button').attr('disabled', '');
        }

        $('.wait').remove();

        if (data.success) {
            alert('success! It should redirect.');
            location = data.success;
        }
        else {
            alert('it worked... but won\'t redirect...');
            alert(data.success);
        }

    }
});
alert('End');
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't parse the response. `data` is still a string.

Set `dataType: 'json'` in the `$.ajax` options.

Even better if you set the right content type for the response in PHP:

```
header('Content-type:  application/json.');
```

Comment: @Robbie: Btw. I've seen you asked a couple questions already (quite a while ago actually ;)) but you did not accept any answer. Did none of them help you? You should accept the most helpful answer by clicking the tick outline next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dataType:'json' or else parse your data response as json with jQuery.parseJson(data)